# Mysql_query return value one but database not effected

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i'm going to update a row into mysql database. the senarius is: taking the values from a form and redirect to another file and set the form values to database using update statement. the problem is that mysql_query return value 1 and does not return any error but when i check the database through phpmyadmin my database doesn't affected.
here is the code

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_name="login_takrim";
    $tbl_name="takrim_users";
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("c$host","$username","$password") or die("can not connect");
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST["txtusername"];
    $mypassword=$_POST["txtpassword"];
    $myemail=$_POST["txtemail"];

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername=stripslashes($myusername);
    $myemail=stripslashes($myemail);
    $mypassword=stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myemail=mysql_real_escape_string($myemail);
    $myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    echo "$myusername $mypassword $myemail";// test to see i get the form value on the php server.
    $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET username = '$myusername' and  password = '$mypassword' and email= '$myemail' where showname='hussein'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());//does not return error 
    echo $result;
    if($result==false)
    {
        echo "no";
    }
    else
    {
        //header("location:setEmail.php");
        echo "yes";

    }


?>
```

Comment: Oh please, don't store passwords in plain text, if your site gets hacked, they'll be all open to everyone's eyes!

Comment: Marcel Korpel what do you mean. should i have to do more?

Comment: Absolutely! You should at least use a good password encryption utility, e.g. the functions at http://php.net/password. A compatibility library for PHP >= 5.3.7 is at https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat. And as Shankar mentioned, you should really stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) using either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).  If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query may excuted correctly may be there was no matching records just do like this

```
    <?php
        $host="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $db_name="login_takrim";
        $tbl_name="takrim_users";
        // Connect to server and select databse.
        mysql_connect("c$host","$username","$password") or die("can not connect");
        mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
        // username and password sent from form 
        $myusername=$_POST["txtusername"];
        $mypassword=$_POST["txtpassword"];
        $myemail=$_POST["txtemail"];

        // To protect MySQL injection
        $myusername=stripslashes($myusername);
        $myemail=stripslashes($myemail);
        $mypassword=stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myemail=mysql_real_escape_string($myemail);
        $myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
        echo "$myusername $mypassword $myemail";// test to see i get the form value on the php server.
        $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET username = '$myusername',  password = '$mypassword',email= '$myemail' where showname='hussein'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());//does not return error 
         if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
         {   
             //header("location:setEmail.php");
            echo "yes";

         }
         else
         {
              echo "no";
          }     




    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chage your **`UPDATE`** statement like this

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET `username` = '$myusername',`password` = '$mypassword',`email`= '$myemail' where `showname`='hussein'";
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `c` here (before `$host`):

```
mysql_connect("c$host","$username","$password") or die("can not connect");
```